# C# reverse navigation with generic types

Tags: c#, generics, aggregation

My classes are similar to these:

```
public class Root<TChild> 
{
   int ID {get;}
   ...
   List<TChild> Children {get;}
}
```

```
public class Child
{
    int IDChild {get;}
    ...
}
```

I need to add the reverse navigation property in Child class to access from Child its Root, but I don't know how to declare the property of `Root<TChild>` type.

**Which type should be TChild in Child class?**

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in .net fiddle and seems to work just fine

```
public class Root<TChild> 
{
   int ID {get;}
   List<TChild> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    int IDChild {get;}
    Root<Child> MyRoot { get; set; }
}

// wherever
var root = new Root<Child> { Children = new List<Child>() };
root.Children.Add(new Child { MyRoot = root });
```

Comment: This works. However it's not exactly my case because i need to add children to root internally the root class. So in the class Root<TChild> i need something like this: `this.Children.Add(new Child { MyRoot = this });` but this don't work because it's impossible convert Root<TChild> to Rott<Child>

Answer (score 0):

This works fine and problem is that you have two classes for same entry better is use one class for every entry in tree.

```
    public class TreeEntity
    {
        private int id = 0;
        private TreeEntity parent = null;
        private IList<TreeEntity> childs = new List<TreeEntity>();

        public TreeEntity(int id)
        {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public void AddChild(TreeEntity child)
        {
            childs.Add(child);
            child.parent = this;
        }
    }
```

or maybe

```
    public class TreeEntity<T>
    {
        private int id = 0;
        private TreeEntity<T> parent = null;
        private IList<TreeEntity<T>> childs = new List<TreeEntity<T>>();
        private T data = null;

        public TreeEntity(int id, T data)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.data = data;
        }

        public void AddChild(TreeEntity<T> child)
        {
            childs.Add(child);
            child.parent = this;
        }
    }
```

however in your case

```
public class Root<TChild> 
{
   int ID {get;}
   ...
   List<TChild> Children {get;}
   ...
   public void addChild(T child)
   {
   Children.add(child)
   child.setParent(this) 
   }
}
```

```
public class Child
{
    int IDChild {get;}
    Root<Child> parent;
    ...
    public void setParent (Root<Child>)  
    {
     this.parent = parent;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have two classes because they aren't the same entity. Imagine root is a order and children are the line item of the order or something similar.

Comment: Problem is in your point of view. You can make `bool isChild` but ok. Like Invoice?

Comment: Just like order and order line. They are different entities but in a relationship of type aggregation, so in order there's a list of order lines. There are many differences in these two entity, in properties and methods.